Is these inequalities a criteria that a real polynomial has only real roots?
Suppose $f(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0\in\mathbb R[x]$ is a real polynomial with indeterminates $a_0,\cdots,a_{n-1}\in\mathbb R$.
Let $z_1,\cdots,z_n$ be all complex roots of $f(x)=0$.
Consider all $\binom n 2$ different pairs $d_{ij}=(z_i-z_j)^2$,
and let $\sigma_1=\sum_{i<j}d_{ij},\cdots,\sigma_{\binom n2}=\prod_{i<j}d_{ij}$
to be all elementary symmetric polynomials of $d_{ij}$-s.
Since they are symmetric polynomials of $z_i$-s, we find that any $\sigma_i=\sigma_i(a_0,\cdots,a_{n-1})$
is a real polynomial of the $a_i$-s.
So my question is, if all $\sigma_i\ge 0$, are all roots $z_i$ real numbers?
This condition is true for $n=2,3$.
A more general problem is whether there exists a finite set of real polynomials $c_1(a_0,\cdots,a_{n-1}),\cdots,c_k(a_0,\cdots,a_{n-1})$ such that all $z_i$-s are real
iff $c_i\ge 0$ for all $i$-s. So it is natural to try these $\sigma_i$-s.
How should I proceed? Is elimination of quantifiers for real closed fields useful to this problem?

Yes, the condition $\sigma_i \ge 0$ for all $i$ is both necessary and sufficient for all of the roots of $f(x)$ to be real.
Consider the polynomial $$\displaystyle{p(x) = \prod_{i<j}(x-d_{ij})}$$ whose roots are the $d_{ij} = (z_i-z_j)^2$ and whose coefficients are $(-1)^i\sigma_i$ by Vieta's formulas.
Note that if the original polynomial $f(x)$ has a non-real root $z$, then $p(x)$ has the negative real root $(z-\bar{z})^2$.
But this is impossible if $\sigma_i \ge 0$ for all $i$, since then the coefficients of $p(x)$ are alternating and thus Descartes' rule of signs implies that $p(x)$ has no negative real roots.
Hence $\sigma_i \ge 0$ implies that $f(x)$ does not have any non-real roots.
You can get similar results with fewer inequalities by applying Sturm's theorem to an arbitrary polynomial.
